# Autocomplete on multiple fields Entity Reference

Tags: entities, nodes, ajax

This is my case:

I have a content type `advertisement` with some fields and an **entity reference** of content type `product`. The **widget type** of the entity reference is **autocomplete**.

These are my settings of the autocomplete field:

[image]

[image]

When I create an `advertisement` I can type in the name of the `product`. But the product has also other fields like **cnk**. How can I make sure the autocomplete will search on the name **AND** the cnk?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the functionality *Views: Filter by an entity reference view* that comes with the Entity Reference module to search on more fields.

To use this functionality you need to change Entity selection mode to *Views: Filter by an entity reference view* instead of *Simple (with optional filter by bundle)* on the settings for your entity reference field.

[image: Entity reference - Entity selection mode - Filter by an entity reference view]

First off you need to setup a View that lists your product nodes. Then add a display of the type Entity Reference.

[image: Entity reference views display]

You can exclude the field cnk from display but **add it as a search field to the settings** for the Format "Entity Reference List". If you don't exclude the field cnk from display it will show content from the field in the autocomplete widget.

[image]

No go back to the entity reference field and choose the view you just created under the settings for *Views: Filter by an entity reference view*.

Comment: Thanks !!! Works like charm. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Autocomplete will search against the referenced entity label (e.g. title).  If you're set on using auto-complete then you may have to write your own custom module to provide alternative auto-complete behavior.

If you simply want to make it easier to search/select a referenced entity then I'd recommend giving the [Entity Reference View Widget](http://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_view_widget) module a try.