# How do I alter entity reference autocomplete results

Tags: views, entities

I have an *Album* content type with some fields, including a *contact* field, which is an *Entity reference* field (taxonomy).

My *contact* taxonomy field has 3 text fields. I want to be able to add a *contact* to my *Album* content type with the autocomplete widget, but I want this autocomplete field to search from all of  my 3 *contact* fields, not only the *title* field (default behavior).

I have also tried to use the functionality *Views: Filter by an entity reference view* that comes with the Entity Reference module (Drupal 8 core) to search on more fields, as seen on https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/125046/57071, but after creating my view, my autocomplete field return me a `500 fatal error` (through AJAX) because of missing fields/relations.

I'm working with Drupal 8.0.2.